# android-sorting of list is not working

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections

I have a list named taskSubList which is made of object .I need to sort the task based on the iscompleted function.But list is not getting sorted.My code is:

```
if(taskSubList.size()!=0)
    {
        for(int position=0;position<taskSubList.size();position++)
        {
            if(taskSubList.get(position).isCompleted()==1)
            {
                Task taskItem = taskSubList.get(position);
                for (int i = position + 1; i < taskSubList.size();i++) {
                    Task taskItem1 = taskSubList.get(i);
                    taskSubList.set(i-1, taskItem1);
                }
            taskSubList.set(taskSubList.size()-1, taskItem);


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: take a look at http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/, it will save you implementing a complicated sorting algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is en error in your sorting algorithm. When you are moving the `completed` element to the end of the list, the current element (with index `position`) is replaced by the next element (from `position+1`). But in the next iteration in the first the `position` is incremented, so you did not process new element (which came from `position+1`).

For example, the list:

(1 completed) (2 completed) (3 incomplete)

After the first iteration you will have:

(2 completed) (3 incomplete) (1 completed)

but the next iteration will start from the element `(3 incomplete)` and the element `(2 completed)` will be missed.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to implement sort yourself it is a good exercise but why not to use `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: Thank you.But I wish to do some exercises on Lists.Thats why i am not using Collections.sort();

Answer (score 0):

i will tell you the flaw i found in your algo.. ,lets assume your 1st 2 elements are completed, and you are shifting towards right.. after 1st loop the 2nd element comes to the 1st position, which you are not checking again.. so it will remain unsorted..

try to use the following algo...

```
if(taskSubList.size()!=0)
    {
        int completedCount = taskSubList.size() - 1;
        for(int position=0;position<taskSubList.size();position++)
        {
            if (position >= completedCount - 1) 
               break;
            if(taskSubList.get(position).isCompleted()==1) {
               // swap elements in position and completedCount
               completedCount--;
               position --;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this code works!!.

```
if(taskSubList.size()!=0)
    {
        for(int position=0;position<taskSubList.size();position++)
        {
            if(taskSubList.get(position).isCompleted()==1)
            {
                for(int i=position+1;i<taskSubList.size();i++)
                {
                    if(taskSubList.get(i).isCompleted()==0)
                    {
                        Task taskItem = taskSubList.get(position);
                        Task taskItem1 = taskSubList.get(i);
                        taskSubList.set(i, taskItem);
                        taskSubList.set(position, taskItem1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```